# Recommended deploy strategies for mobile apps that share 99% of the same repository?

Tags: react-native, deployment, fastlane, strategy-pattern, white-labelling

We have a white labeled mobile app that is being deployed as several different apps. Each with its own branding. However, they each share 99% of the same code.

The more we white label the more repository creep there is. We are painstakingly cherry-picking edits to each individual app.

The best circumstance would be to keep all the code in a core repository. And making only the unique edits ( for branding ) to the individual repos.

Our deploy stack is : Fastlane, ReactNative

Any recommends on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like you. I definitely merge all apps in the same repository. We only had to make a diferent branch for each of them and merge when we had something with the same code.